Merging 'confirmation bias' questions?
A recent question raised the topic of confirmation bias yet again:
Is there any research showing we only like to see/read information on themes/topics/ideas we like?
I know of the following previous one (one by me):

Do people have a tendency to stick to one opinion after they formed it?
How to refer to the phenomenon of people only absorbing evidence which confirms their beliefs?
Official term for the tendency to associate with like-minded people?

Should we perhaps start thinking of closing them as duplicate and making one the canonical answer?

In my comment here: Are all conscious experiences stored as memories?, I list out 9 questions related to "infinite memory capacity", which I think are all practically the same.
A related question is what to do about sub-topics?  Sometimes a broad question is asked (and possibly answered), and then later, another question is asked that is a more specific version of the previous.  An example is: "Is typical dating coach advice science-based?" and "Is the dating coach advice given by Joe Romance science-based?"
We have a system in place already for marking and voting on duplicates.  If you feel that the above questions are duplicates and should be closed in favour of one of them, then go ahead and mark them as such, and if the community agrees, then it will happen.
A more brazen approach would be to edit an existing question or even add a new one with a comprehensive scope that more clearly covers everything touched on by other questions, and then marking them as duplicates.
Either way, I don't think CS.meta is a good place to make such decisions.

I agree with the suggested approaches, but disagree this meta (I presume you meant CogSci.meta ;p) can't be used to discuss this. With the limited amount of active users we have merely close voting questions requires mod intervention (less so nowadays). I believe closing as duplicates is even more troublesome. How do we decide which becomes the 'canonical' question?
